# Generate UUID and get Least and Most significant bits in Javascript

Tags: javascript, uuid

I need to generate a random UUID in Javascript and get the Least and Most significant bits from it (like in Java's UUID class). I found enough scripts to generate the UUID, but wasn't able to find a script that gets the least and most significant bits. (I don't need the UUID itself, though).

Thanks in advance,

Chrisstar

Comment: what do you mean by least and most significant bits? maybe make example of the output results from an UUID

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) will help

Comment: look at this maybe it gives some hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192099/uuid-string-from-most-least-significant-bits-in-javascript it is similar to your question.

Comment: This sadly doesnt help me, I need to do this backwards.

Comment: I understand you what I can do up vote your question and hope some body can contribute, good luck